# math.pow Form Input Values Processing

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I asked and was advised previously about unpacking tuple with (*variable) to process exponent function that takes 2 values separated by commas, in using Python in command line. But now I'm going live on GAE and of course I need a form. The * unpacking thing is just giving 500 server errors. Someone also mentioned split...if I need to use that, how/where to? These are user-submitted form values, not static values. The form below works, but I'm stumped how to process (print) result to user.

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage(keep_blank_values=1)
raw = form.getvalue('input')

<html>
<body>
<p>Enter base and exponent, separated by a comma.</p>
<form method='post' action="/">
<input type = 'text' name='input'/></p> 
<input type = 'submit' value="Calc"></p>
</form>
```

UPDATE per Dan D's response. The problem (500 error) is between form values and map/split function. The form input type is set to 'text' and map is int...is that the problem? Whatever the case it's not working.

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage(keep_blank_values=1)
raw = form.getvalue('input')
processed = map(int, raw.split(","))
readout = pow(*map(int, processed.split(",")))
if raw !="":
    print readout
else: 
    print""
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case that `raw` is `"3,6"`:

```
>>> raw = "3,6"
>>> map(int, raw.split(","))
[3, 6]
>>> pow(*map(int, raw.split(",")))
729
```

Comment: Thanks for response and showing how to use map and split with static values. I'm posting revision with form values, as mentioned that is what I'm using, not static values. There's where my problem now lies.